# How to create large page

Tags: posts

I have page (not a post), which html output is about 150kB, which WP cuts, when pasted into editor. How to set WP for large pages?

Comment: Please expand your post to include more details about how exactly the content is truncated. Show relevant code (such as the spot where the HTML is truncated) and be as specific as possible about how someone might recreate the issue. The page vs. post shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Welcome aboard! Please, read the [How to Ask section](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) of the FAQ. And if you plan to be sailing around, read everything ;)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the WP schema allows for **~4GB** of post content, I'd say the trouble is something else:

- Got any plugins running? Disable them all & try again.
- Made any changes to core files? Restore to a default install.

What kind of content are you pasting in?